# conflict between two jquery plugins with same function name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am working in a large site that has 2 conflicting jquery plugins included for doing autocmplete.

1) jquery.autocomplete.js (not part of jquery ui) that does :

```
$.fn.extend({
    autocomplete: function   ...
```

2)  jquery.ui.autocomplete.js (from the latest jquery ui library), that also uses the autocomplete keyword.

```
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {   ...
```

Is there a way to specify that i am using only the second, jquery.ui widget
when calling

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete ...
```

without changing the 2 files?

Comment: jquery.autocomplete.js seems to have been a separate project on github while jquery.ui.autocomplete is the official jquery plugin. Can you not just use 1 and remove the other fullstop? Does the official ui autocomplete not do everything you need it to? It just doesn't seem they were intented to work side-by-side

Comment: i cant change or remove jquery.autocomplete.js , and i think what i have is a inhouse version and not the git version you are reffering to.  a possible solution would be to  be able to access the second (ui) version with something like $( "#tags" ).ui.autocomplete

Comment: "Don't use one" isn't really a solution for a name conflict at all.  Also, saying two libraries weren't intended to work together, just because they have the same name, makes no sense; they're not necessarily even aware of each other's existence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the second autocomplete is using the `$.Widget` method of registering itself with jQuery it'll be easiest to change the behaviour of the in-house one.

You won't be able to load both of them without making *some* sort of change to the jQuery object between the two script loads because they'll just conflict with (or overwrite) each other.

I would try this:

```
<script src="jquery.autocomplete.js"> </script>
<script>
    // rename the local copy of $.fn.autocomplete
    $.fn.ourautocomplete = $.fn.autocomplete;
    delete $.fn.autocomplete;
</script>
<script src="jquery-ui.autocomplete.js"> </script>
```

Which will then make:

```
$().autocomplete()
```

use the jQuery UI version, and

```
$().ourautocomplete()
```

use your local version.

Comment: This is brilliant

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do it with the tabs function of jQuery UI, it should work the same for you.
A function is technically a js object, so you could simply rename it :

```
    $.fn.tabs2 = $.fn.tabs;
    delete $.fn.tabs;
    $("#tabz").tabs2({});
```

Hope that helps!

**Edit**

Like Alnitak suggested, you also need to delete the previous function's name.
Also, I think .fn is required.

Comment: nice idea, but i tried this and it doesent seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/turaaa/mbZgS/

Comment: Like Alnitak suggested, you also need to delete the previous function's name.

Comment: @GilZumbrunnen and it's important that you do that _before_ you try to load the second function!