# vertical accordion function naming issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using two accordion on my website.One is JqueryUI and other one is here:

http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html

Now the issue is that both of them are using .accordion to initialize the accordion. And in this case only one will work.

Is there any way I can fix this function naming issue?

To initialize Jquery-UI I'm using this:

```
$( ".jquery-ui-accordion" ).accordion();
```

To initialize the other one (Nested accordion) I'm using this:

```
$("html").addClass("js");
$.fn.accordion.defaults.container = false; 
$(function() {
  $("#acc3").accordion({initShow : "#current"});
  $("#acc1").accordion({
      el: ".h", 
      head: "h4, h5", 
      next: "div", 
      initShow : "div.outer:eq(1)"
  });
  $("#acc2").accordion({
      obj: "div", 
      wrapper: "div", 
      el: ".h", 
      head: "h4, h5", 
      next: "div", 
      showMethod: "slideFadeDown",
      hideMethod: "slideFadeUp",
      initShow : "div.shown",
      elToWrap: "sup, img"
    });
  $("html").removeClass("js");
});

});
```

Please note both of them are using `.accordion()` function.

Comment: Please post sample code.

Comment: What do you mean with `both of them are using .accordion to initialize the accordion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code right after jQuery UIs javascript include and before other accordions javascript include:

```
jQuery.fn.myCustomAccordion = jQuery.fn.accordion;
delete $.fn.accordion;
```

And then you can use both accordions, e.g:

```
// jQuery accordion
$( ".jquery-ui-accordion" ).myCustomAccordion(); 

// "Other accordion"
$("#acc3").accordion({initShow : "#current"});
...
```

Comment: Should I create a js file and place jQuery.fn.myCustomAccordion = jQuery.fn.accordion;
delete $.fn.accordion;  in it and then load it in the middle?

Comment: You can do this, yeah. Or you place that code in a `script`-Tag.

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898992/conflict-between-two-jquery-plugins-with-same-function-name/11900999#11900999

Answer (score 1):

If they are both named `.accordion` you are stating that the CSS class name is being used as a selector, correct? So I would recommend using a unique `id` next to each classname to differentiate the two `.accordion`. But without code examples it’s hard to help further.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the function name, you can simply roll up your sleeves and rename the function in one of the source code files.

OR you could *not* use two plugins that do the same thing...

Update: I have a better idea of what you're trying to do now. I have used jquery.collapsible-menus.js for the exact same thing. It uses lists rather than divs, but it's easy to get going.

http://tommcfarlin.com/collapsible-menus-for-jquery-1-1/

Comment: Please don't ask me to look in their library :)

Comment: I have just made an edit to point you to what I think is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, got it fixed with Simon's answer.Actually I have done a lot of design changes on that accordion to suite my design and now I don't want to move to a new accordion.